# VueJS Downloadable PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, vue.js, vue-router

I'm using vue-router for all my routes which i've declared like this:

```
      {
        path: '/about',
        name: 'about',
        component: About
    },
    {
        path: '/home',
        name: 'home',
        component: Home
    },
    {
        path: '*',
        redirect: '/'
    }
```

The problem I have is, on the Home component I have a link to a PDF which when clicked should open a PDF in the browser.  But when I click the link to the PDF it gives an error of

```
Cannot GET /assets/pdf/statistics.pdf
```

Even though the file is there.  I have a feeling vue-router is causing this because it's not a specified route.

Can anyone help on how I get around this please?

Comment: Where are you seeing the "Cannot GET" error - in the browser console? What happens if you attempt to get to the pdf directly by pasting the url in your browser's location bar?

Comment: The error shows up in the browser.  Thanks for replying but I've figured out it was a webpack error.

Comment: I have the same issue. A btn where I want to dl a pdf. Can you explain how did you fixit ?

Comment: @Ragnar I managed to make it work by creating a folder called downloads inside my Assets folder then something like this, but I made it into a mixin to re-use it:

` data() {
        return {
            fileOne: '/static/downloads/file1.pdf',
            fileTwo: '/static/downloads/file2.pdf'  
            }
    },

    methods: {
        viewFileOne() {
            window.open( this.fileOne, '_blank');
        },
        viewFileTwo() {
            window.open(this.fileTwo, '_blank');

        }
    }`